# Finding the "one" in a one-to-many by searching a comma-delimited list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables, `Clients` and `Physicians`. Each `Client` has a list of primary keys for their physicians (`PhysicianIds`), which is flattened to a comma-delimited string for database storage (`PhysicianStore`).

One of my action methods requires finding which client a physician belongs to, but I can't find a way to do this without evaluating the entire table with `.ToList()`. The below code doesn't work because `.Split()` doesn't work with LINQ-to-Entities.

Do I need to add a foreign key to `Physician`?

```
// Data model / DTO
public class ClientModel
{
    public List<int> PhysicianIds { get; set; }
    public string PhysicianStore
    {
        get { return string.Join(",", PhysicianIds.ConvertAll<string>(i => i.ToString())); }
        set { PhysicianIds = value.Split(',').Select(str => int.Parse(str)).ToList(); }
        //set { PhysicianIds = value.Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll<int>(str => int.Parse(str)); }
    }
}

public class PhysiciansController
{   
    // Disposed in full code
    private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        PhysicianModel pm = await db.Physicians.FindAsync(id);
        if (pm == null)
        {
            return HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        // Have to use PhysicianStore here because PhysicianIds is not a column in the DB
        return View(new PhysicianDetailsViewModel(pm, db.Clients.Where(c => c.PhysicianStore.Split(',').Contains(pm.Id.ToString()))
                                                                                                       .FirstOrDefault()?.Name));
    }
}
```

Edit: Per comments, I really should be using navigation properties. I'll pursue this and ask another question if needed.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @Stephen Good point, but I don't see a solution in those answers.

Comment: I was just pointing out how bad it is to have a comma-delimited string for database storage :)

Comment: @Stephen I agree, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You should follow an EntityFramework tutorial, just search in Google One-To-Many EntityFramework.
You will come up with navigation properties that should help you with your problem.

Comment: Ignoring the table design, what's the actual issue with your code - `string.Split` not supported in LINQ to Entities?

Comment: I don't really see the one-to-many relation from a logical point of view. Wouldn't a physician have multiple clients, making the whole thing a many-to-many?

Comment: @IvanStoev Crap, forgot that. Yes, that's the issue.

Comment: @grek40 Each client has several physicians. Physicians aren't at several practices, which is what a client is here.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense (ignoring the 2-job-physicians). Can you add your Physician model class?

Comment: @grek40 I could do that after I sleep (2:30 AM here), but I'm not sure why it's relevant.

Comment: Basically, it is relevant because with the "right" design of Physician, retrieving the associated client should be completely trivial. So there is something wrong with your current design, else you would never ask the question.

Comment: @Sinjai So if `physicians aren't at several practices`, why not simply give your `Physician` a `ClientId`, instead of trying to push many `PhysicianIds` on your `Client`? This is how you should be handling it for a one-to-many relationship, **every item in the "many" should have a single reference to an item in the "one"**. Many physicians are able to refer to the same `ClientId`, but every physician will only have one `ClientId`.

Comment: @Flater I guess that didn't/doesn't make sense to me logistically. Then the only way to list a client's physicians is by searching the entire `Physicians` table, no?

Comment: @grek40 There's nothing worthwhile to see there because `Physician` has no foreign key, like the question says. See the above comments between Flater/myself for that.

Comment: Ok, then the answer is *"Add a foreign key to the Physician entity and remove the Id list from client."*. Is that enough for you?

Comment: @grek40 Not sure how to manage that, which is the only reason the relationship is one-way right now. I assume the answer to that is "navigation properties do it automagically".

Comment: Well *\*surprise\** you have to implement some changes in the `Physicians` class and I don't see why I should invent such a class for an answer if you *for whatever reason* decide it's not going into the question.

Comment: @grek40 I was going to ask a new question because the problem of the question changed when the suggestion moved to "use navigation properties". As always, you're under no obligation to answer.

Comment: @Sinjai `SELECT * FROM Physicians WHERE ClientId = 123` You don't need to list the whole table. Searching a table is not an expensive operation, PK/FK fields are indexed and optimized for quick searching. Besides, even if you were to get a comma separated list of physician IDs from your client, you would **still** have to query the `Physicians` table to retrieve the physicians, so your point is somewhat moot :)

Comment: @Flater Very good point. Someone else said both of them should have a foreign key though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the database design, the main issue as I understand is that LINQ to Entities does not support `string.Split`. But `string.Concat`, `string.Contains` and `ToString` are supported, so you can use the following trick:

```
var token = "," + pm.Id.ToString() + ",";

var query = db.Clients
    .Where(c => ("," + c.PhysicianStore + ",").Contains(token));
```

The trick is to enclose with `","` both the search and target terms. This way it handles correctly the start, end and middle elements of the list, and will not produced false positives when searching for let say `"1"` inside `"12,21"`.

Comment: Clever bandaid, thanks. Quick question that doesn't warrant its own post: Is either of the two setters of `PhysicianStore` superior? There's a 99% chance it will be getting removed anyway, but for the sake of my education...

Comment: It really doesn't matter. I personally prefer the variants with general `Select` for both getter and setter rather than `List<T>` specific methods like `ConvertAll`.